# makefile compiling C source files on Ubuntu

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to compile various c files with one makefile on Ubuntu 12.04.

This is the code:

```
myprog: main.o assembler.o print.o secondPass.o
    gcc -g -ansi -Wall main.o assembler.o print.o secondPass.o -o myprog
main.o: main.c
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall main.c -o main.o
assembler.o: assembler.c
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall assembler.c -o assembler.o
print.o: print.c
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall print.c -o print.o
secondPass.o: secondPass.c
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall secondPass.c -o secondPass.o
```

I don't see any spaces here that are not belong, and the error I get is the following:

```
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: What is the output of `make -v`?

Comment: Also, does `make -n` run successfully?  If so, the problem is as CMoi says below, a problem with the execution of the `gcc` command, and not a problem with your makefile as I said.

Comment: From the error message it's unquestionably true that the problem is as @CMoi describes.  We don't have to run `make -v` or `make -n` to know that.  Make prints that message when a command it invoked from a recipe exited with a non-0 exit code (in this case, `1`).  That means it successfully parsed the makefile, which means the problem is _NOT_ related to TAB vs. space or a syntax error in the makefile.

Comment: @Alan: we can't diagnose the problem based on this.  The error message you provided rules out some possible failures, but you need to show _all_ the error messages generated, not just the last one.  In fact, in programming the last error is often fairly useless: the _first_ error is the one you care about.  This is because once things start to go bad, it's likely you'll get "cascading errors" where the system is in a bad state from the previous error and so continues to generate errors.  Sometimes it can recover, but generally you should fix the first error first.

Comment: @MadScientist thank you. I am looking at my main program now and I will bring the results once I finished with it.

Answer (score 2):

**Addendum**: Having read the other discussion in this thread, I believe the explanation below is most likely *not* the cause of the original problem.

---

You have indented the commands with four spaces.  But you need to indent them with a single tab character; spaces will not work. Make is notorious for being sensitive in this way, and it drives everyone crazy.

I tried your makefile, but with the four-space indents replaced with tab-indents, and it worked with Gnu Make 3.81.

If you cannot fix your makefile using your editor, you could try fixing your makefile  by running the command:

```
 perl -i -lpe 's/^    /\t/' Makefile
```

which tells Perl to replace each instance of four spaces with a tab (`\t`).

Comment: I did use tab key but my gedit sets them to width 4. How long should my tab be? @MJD

Comment: Tab is a special character, not a sequence of spaces.  I do not know enough about gedit to advise you on how to get it to produce a tab character when you press the tab key.  There may be a configuration option named "use hard tabs" or something of the sort.  The correct answer may be to stop using gedit and start using an editor like vim or emacs that was designed for programming work.

Comment: Thank you, I will try. So far my terminal gave me the same miskate when using tab as an eight-space function.

Comment: Tab is not an eight-space function.  It is a single tab character, which is different, just as the letter `F` and the digit `7` are different characters.

Comment: I did what you said with the command, it did change my makefile, however the error remains. I wonder if it's a problem with my gedit.

Comment: @Alan Ignore this. He's trying to confuse you by using SO-enforced code block styles to cause problems.

Comment: @Alan: it's crystal clear from the error you provided in your question that this (TAB vs. spaces) is NOT your problem: the error message would be completely different if that were the case.

Comment: @ciphermagi _'Ignore this. He's trying to confuse you ...'_ **No!** Using `\t` for makefiles is essential, and most probably the OP's `gedit` settings are replacing these tab characters with spaces, which would cause such problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your error doesn't seem to be in the Makefile. You should have another error before that one.

I believe `gcc -c -ansi -Wall main.c -o main.o` is failing, for example if I put some random crap in main.c:

```
$ make
gcc -c -ansi -Wall main.c -o main.o
main.c:1:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ at end of input
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score -3):

A simple makefile should look similar to this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -Wall
VPATH=Anagram:Permutation:Russian

all: anagram permutation russian

anagram: check_off.c count.c sort.c utility.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Anagram/check_off.c Anagram/utility.c -o check_off
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Anagram/count.c Anagram/utility.c -o count
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Anagram/sort.c Anagram/utility.c -o sort

permutation: permutation.c randint.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Permutation/permutation.c Permutation/randint.c -o permutation

russian: russian.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Russian/russian.c -o russian

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm check_off count sort permutation russian
```

Comment: That does not address the question, and your example has exactly the same problem as the one in the question.

Comment: What @ciphermage is saying is that you CANNOT ADD A TAB (that shows up like a TAB with an 8-space indent) in StackOverflow code blocks.  If you put a TAB in your question or answer and indent it with 4 spaces so it shows up as a code block, it will show as indented 4 spaces.  This is a "feature" of StackOverflow's code formatting/display capabilities, so it's incorrect to assume that any time you see a makefile in an SO question where recipes are indented by 4 spaces, that means that the original makefile has a TAB vs. space problem.  Look at the actual error message, it will tell you.

Comment: @MJD I agree this is not a good answer to the question asked.  I'm just saying that continuing to point out the "same problem" of using 4 spaces is not valid... your answer is also incorrect and does nothing to address the question either.